# How to detect MTP/PTP device in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, usb-drive

I want to detect the MTP/PTP device when it plugs in the android device. I know there is one method using Intent: `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and then defining meta-data which using resource like `<usb-device class="6" subclass="1" protocol="1">`, but it doesn't work. The system doesn't send this intent to the registered application.

Thus, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the machine to act as USB host by adding  into
[AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please specify what is the device you are using for testing?
It is very likely that your device has no PTP/MTP specific values in class, subclass and protocol for the USB device descriptor and/or interface descriptor.
See this: http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Media%20Transfer%20Protocol.pdf
Some devices advertise themselves as Mass Storage devices or Vendor Specific.
If that is the case the only way is to try matching the vendor id and product id of the devices you would like to support.
Here is also a list of MTP devices with their vendor id and product id: http://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/code/ci/HEAD/tree/src/music-players.h.

Hope this helps.